# How to recovery hdfs by HA second namenode?

Tags: hadoop

The situation is as follows：

I accidentally re format the namenode node in Hadoop.

I now have a spare namenode as well as all the datanode nodes.

I lost the master namenode and all the journal nodes of the file.

Excuse me, how to restore the HDFS system through the spare namenode node?

Answer (score 0):

Easy thing would be 
restart the cluster without primary namenode. DataNodes and Secondary Namenode will restore by it self.